# How to Search for Specific Text inside URL

Tags: python, url

I would like to get specific data from URL used for poll. I search some topics about it. I found BeautifulSoup and Request libs. However, I confuse how to take my data. Here is the last output and a I only need

Vote 10: `int()`

Vote 9: `int()`

so on...

***output***

```
<p class="option-text"><span>10</span> <span class="option-count" data-count="1">1</span></p>
<p class="option-text"><span>9</span> <span class="option-count" data-count="0">0</span></p>
<p class="option-text"><span>8</span> <span class="option-count" data-count="0">0</span></p>
<p class="option-text"><span>7</span> <span class="option-count" data-count="0">0</span></p>
<p class="option-text"><span>6</span> <span class="option-count" data-count="0">0</span></p>
<p class="option-text"><span>5</span> <span class="option-count" data-count="0">0</span></p>
<p class="total-votes"><span data-count="1" id="vote-count">1</span> Votes</p>
<p class="total-comments"><span data-count="0" id="comment-count">0</span> Comments</p>
<p class="poll-dupe-setting">
<span>IP Duplication Checking</span>
</p>
```

Comment: It's properly called web *scraping* – that may be why you were not able to find any example.

Comment: ups. I changed what I looking for. Then, I found BeautifulSoup and Request. Is there any good link that you can share. @usr2564301 I edit my code with your help than you

Comment: for simple examples of `beautifulsoup` -> https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/